# Set text color in CFMutableAttributedStringRef and pass to Obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, nsattributedstring, core-foundation

I'm creating a `CFMutableAttributedStringRef` with attributes and then passing this to Objective-C.

```
return (__bridge NSAttributedString *)myAttributedStringRef;
```

Most attributes like fonts have toll-free bridging with their Obj-C counterparts but not color attributes.  `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` and `kCTForegroundColorAttributeName` do not bridge nor do `UIColor` and `CGColorRef`.

For example, I'm setting the text color like this but it doesn't bridge to it's Obj-C counterpart.

```
CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(string, range, kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, myCGColor);
```

Is it possible to somehow set the text color in core foundation and then pass this to Obj-C?